# Passing a java object to MSQL DB through a store procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to create a JBDC Struct from my java application for which i need to pass that object to a MSSQL Database table. This is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*; 

  try{
       Struct emp = jdbcConn.createStruct("udtIntArray", new Object[] { 99,12 });
       logger.trace("Array printed"+ emp);
       }
  catch(SQLException e) {
       logger.trace( "Struct creation error SQL error");
       logger.trace(logIdent+""+e);
   }
```

My udtIntArray creation

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE udtIntArray AS OBJECT { 
        val    INT[],
}
```

But i am getting a **method createStruct(java.lang.String, [I) not found** error

**detailed error**:
*Caused by: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: BeanShell script error: bsh.EvalError: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import java.sql.*;   import java.util.*;    import java.util.List;   import java . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method createStruct(java.lang.String, [I) not found in class'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection' : at Line: 199 : in file: inline evaluation of:`import java.sql.*;   import java.util.*;    import java.util.List;   import java . . . '' : jdbcConn .createStruct ( "IntArray" , objects )*

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the SQL statement that creates the `udtIntArray` type in the database?

Comment: @Abra, check my edit